# Access is denied in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

when i login through any account and click on fiancne documents then it show me this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
  Access is denied.
  Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve 
   this         request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested
      URL.

  Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.
          Verify          that you have permission to view this directory or page 
        based on the       credentials you supplied and the authentication methods 
    enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional 
    assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4984; ASP.NET 
      Version:2.0.50727.4971
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your documents are in a protected folder that can't be served up to the user that you are using, or possibly to any users.  Check the security on the folder where your finance documents are stored.

If you aren't on the development team, then I would suggest contacting your website administrator to have them co-ordinate to determine what the issue is.